# How I get TagName from JSON GoogleDirection

Tags: java, android

I try of calculate distance and travel time between two points, I'm using the below method, the problema is that i dont Know to get the TagName: Distance TEXT and Duration TEXT from JSON file, for to pass it like String to an TextView

```
public void test2() throws JSONException {

    JSONObject locationJsonObject = new JSONObject();
    locationJsonObject.put("origin", "54.406505,18.67708");
    locationJsonObject.put("destination", "54.446251,18.570993");
    LatlngCalc(locationJsonObject);
}
private void LatlngCalc(JSONObject locationJsonObject) throws JSONException {

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ge_Traker_maps.this);
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/" +
            "json?origins=" + locationJsonObject.getString("origin") + "&destinations=" + locationJsonObject.getString("destination") + "&mode=driving&" +
            "language=en-EN&sensor=false";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    tv4.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500));

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            tv4.setText("That didn't work!");
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

JSON File sample:

```
"rows":[
{
"elements":[
{
"distance":{
"text": "15.2 Km"
"value": 15167
},
"duration":{
"text": "24 mins"
"value": 1466
},
"status": "ok"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code assumes your using `com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple` library. Also it uses url in your question `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=54.406505,18.67708&destinations=54.446251,18.570993&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false`

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

try {
  Object json = jsonParser.parse(jsonString);

  JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) json;

  JSONArray rowsArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("rows");

  for (Object aRow : rowsArray) {
    JSONObject aRowObject = (JSONObject) aRow;

    JSONArray elementArray = (JSONArray) aRowObject.get("elements");

    for (Object anElement : elementArray) {
      JSONObject distanceObj = (JSONObject) ((JSONObject) anElement).get("distance");

      String text = (String) distanceObj.get("text");
      long value = Long.valueOf((String) distanceObj.get("value"));

      System.out.println(text + " " + value);
    }
  }
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    JSONObject distance = object.getJSONObject("distance");

    if (distance.has("distance") && !distance.getString("distance").equals("")) {

     String text = distance.getString("text");
     String value = distance.getString("value");

    }
JSONObject duration = object.getJSONObject("duration");
    if (duration.has("duration") && !duration.getString("duration").equals("")) {

     String text = duration.getString("text");
     String value = duration.getString("value");

    }
```

Comment: Hi i try this: `public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject distance = object.getJSONObject("distance");

                            if (distance.has("distance") && !distance.getString("distance").equals("")) {

                                String text = distance.getString("text");` But cannot resolve symbol object, im sorry i noob in this